# Meaning of ～したいぐらい

Tags: grammar

I want to understand the meaning of this sentence

> 壁紙にしたいぐらい写真。

I was thinking the meaning literally could be "Your photograph is beautiful to be set as my wallpaper", but I argue about the にしたいぐらい part because when I google にしたいぐらい, I found this

> 私を独り占めにしたいぐらい好きで仕方ない。

and I can't relate the meaning of にしたいぐらい here with my previous sentence.

Could someone tell me the best meaning of にしたいぐらい?

Answer (score 1):

- したい = *"want to do"*
- くらい (ぐらい in combinations) = *"amount, degree"* -- in usage, *"so much so or enough that [previous part of the sentence]"*

Putting this together with your sample, we have:

- 壁紙{かべがみ}にしたぐらい[な]写真{しゃしん}

The sample sentence as-is is a bit odd to my ear; the な above is needed to make this grammatical.  Parsing it out:

- [壁紙]{wallpaper} + [に]{into, as} + [したい]{want to do, use, make} + [ぐらい]{so much so that} + [な]{grammatical modifier} + [写真]{photograph}

→

- *"a photo that I would want to use as a wallpaper"*

The ぐらい makes this statement more of a hypothetical: it's not a photo that the speaker **definitely and specifically** wants to use as a wallpaper, and instead it's a photo that the speaker **would** want to use as a wallpaper.

Comment: 「壁紙にしたいぐらい**の**写真」のほうがいいような気が・・

Comment: @chocolate: あっ、そうでしょうか。ググって見ましたらやはり「～ぐらい **の** 」のほうが多いようです。勉強になりました。使い方が地域によって異なるかどうか知りますか？数年前東北にはしばらく住んでいましたが、あの辺には「～ぐらい **な** 」が使われている記憶がありますけれど、もう記憶が薄くなってしまい自分を疑うくらいです。

Comment: I would say "a photo that *to some degree* I would want to use as a wallpaper".

Comment: 「～センチぐらいの+[名詞]」「～ぐらいの大きさ」「～くらいの量」「～歳くらいの人」などでは「な」はダメですが、「～ぐらいの気持ち」「～くらいの感じ」「～くらいの気分」などでは「な」を使う人も結構いるような気がします・・・。「XXくらいな」の時は、「くらい」は quotative な役目をしてるのかな、という気もします・・・

Comment: "a photo that to some degree I would want to use as a wallpaper" >> Why? Here, the 壁紙にしたい modifies the noun くらい, so the ぐらい cannot mean "to some extent". 「壁紙にしたいくらいの写真」 practically means 「壁紙にしたいくらい良い写真」, "a photo which is good **to the extent that** I would want to use as a wallpaper."

Comment: "The photo (so good that) I would really want to make this a wallpaper"